# Rounding error in generating perfect squares python

Tags: python, floating-point-precision, perfect-square

I am trying to find all the values of n such that (2^n-7) is a perfect square. My code is:

```
import math

def isperfect(n):
      return math.sqrt(n) % 1 == 0


print [i for i in range(3,200) if isperfect(2**(i)-7)]
```

Here is what i am getting:

`[3, 4, 5, 7, 15, 58, 60, 62, 64, 66, 68, 70, 72, 74, 76, 78, 80, 82, 84, 86, 88, 90, 92, 94, 96, 98, 100, 102, 104, 106, 108, 110, 112, 114, 116, 118, 120, 122, 124, 126, 128, 130, 132, 134, 136, 138, 140, 142, 144, 146, 148, 150, 152, 154, 156, 158, 160, 162, 164, 166, 168, 170, 172, 174, 176, 178, 180, 182, 184, 186, 188, 190, 192, 194, 196, 198]`

I know it is correct for until n=15, but after that it is all wrong as the next n should be 238. What i understand so far is that the problem is caused to the rounding error for large decimal points in the `sqrt(n)`. Is there a way to resolve the problem.